# Arch linux sudden massive disk writes

Tags: arch-linux

I am running arch linux on my desktop computer and since about two months I sometimes see a massive unrealistic amount of disk writes to my 960 EVO (M.2). I have written a small script to print disk reads/writes since system boot in human-readable numbers (using /sys/block/device/stat) which usually prints very reasonable numbers. When the massive disk write happens, it takes about 5 seconds where my computer is lagging a little. Then, I run my script again (I'm checking it regularly) and disk writes increased from 10GB to ~150GB. I have no idea what the cause is and if these writes are even real (maybe writes to the SSD cache?), but my question is: How can I possibly debug and find out which process is causing these writes or is there anything else I can do? I'm afraid that my disk wears out a lot.

Here, I managed to screenshot the last part of the write, the peaks were actually about double of what you can see in width. I think 20GiB/s is a little too much, even for a good SSD...
[image: Screenshot of disk usage in system monitor]

Comment: when this happen, do `sudo iotop` this will show you application doing read write access on your disk.

Comment: Was `fstrim.service` running at the time? It is set to trim your SSD devices on a regular basis.

Comment: @Kiwy Thanks, but mostly my computer is hanging up so I can only check afterwards...

Comment: @Mioriin That's a good thought! I don't know though. I will check next time, but the numbers being displayed by journalctl (about 135GB trimmed) seem very reasonable to me.

Comment: @Mioriin That's the solution, you're right. So I think I don't have to worry about my SSD anymore, thank you.